# Powershell Form Button onclick event doesn't work as expected

Tags: forms, powershell, user-interface, button

I need to build a prototype of a GUI with powershell.
The OnClick `$Bcancel.add_click({$form.Close})` event doesn't start when clicked.

Here is a shortened version of my script.

```
# Version: 2.0              #  
# Stand: 12. September 2017 #
#############################

Import-Module ActiveDirectory

# Deklarierung

$ActiveApp = "FIS"
$ComboBoxApp = @("eGov","FIS","VI","DV","Axioma","Liegenschaften","HR Portal","Tutoris")
$ComboBoxUrgency = @("Geringe Dringlichkeit","Mittlere Dringlichkeit","Höchste Dringlichkeit")
$ComboBoxPrioT = @("Geringe Prorität","Mittlere Priorität","Höchste Priorität")
$ComboBoxCategory = @("Systemausfall","Unerklärliches Systemverhalten")
$ActiveUser
$CoordinatorGroup = "BFO Management"

# Declaration for POB
$CaseType
$Description
$CDAChangetyp
$Urgency
$CaseCategory
$ContactOrganisation
$ContactCustomer
$ContactNotifyby
$IsOkForWeb
$Coordinator
$Responsible
$Reference
$memo
$XMLBuffer = "*********** XML Buffer ***********"


 #Recognizes the active user

    $ActiveUserNP = Get-WMIObject -class Win32_ComputerSystem | select username
    $ActiveUser1 = $ActiveUserNP.username


    ############################################# Fenster #############################################

    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

    $Form = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
    $Form.Text = "VRSG | Support Ticket - $ActiveApp"
    $Form.TopMost = $true
    $Form.Width = 600
    $Form.Height = 570

    ############################################# Linke Reihe #############################################

    $labelTitel = New-Object system.windows.Forms.Label
    $labelTitel.Text = "VRSG |"
    $LabelTitel.ForeColor = "#009454"
    $labelTitel.AutoSize = $true
    $labelTitel.Width = 25
    $labelTitel.Height = 10
    $labelTitel.location = new-object system.drawing.point(20,20)
    $labelTitel.Font = "Arial Narrow,16,style=Bold"
    $Form.controls.Add($labelTitel)

    $labelTitel2 = New-Object system.windows.Forms.Label
    $labelTitel2.Text = "Support"
    $labelTitel2.AutoSize = $true
    $labelTitel2.Width = 25
    $labelTitel2.Height = 10
    $labelTitel2.location = new-object system.drawing.point(85,20)
    $labelTitel2.Font = "Arial Narrow,16,style=Bold"
    $Form.controls.Add($labelTitel2)

    $label2 = New-Object system.windows.Forms.Label
    $label2.Text = "Application Incident"
    $label2.AutoSize = $true
    $label2.Width = 25
    $label2.Height = 10
    $label2.location = new-object system.drawing.point(20,80)
    $label2.Font = "Arial Narrow,14,style=Bold"
    $Form.controls.Add($label2)


    $LabelAllg = New-Object system.windows.Forms.Label
    $LabelAllg.Text = "General Information"
    $LabelAllg.AutoSize = $true
    $LabelAllg.Width = 25
    $LabelAllg.Height = 10
    $LabelAllg.location = new-object system.drawing.point(20,120)
    $LabelAllg.Font = "Arial Narrow,12,style=Bold"
    $Form.controls.Add($LabelAllg)


    $LabelBet = New-Object system.windows.Forms.Label
    $LabelBet.Text = "Title *"
    $LabelBet.AutoSize = $true
    $LabelBet.Width = 25
    $LabelBet.Height = 10
    $LabelBet.location = new-object system.drawing.point(20,155)
    $LabelBet.Font = "Arial Narrow,10,style=Bold"
    $Form.controls.Add($LabelBet)


    $tbBetreff = New-Object system.windows.Forms.TextBox
    $tbBetreff.Width = 250
    $tbBetreff.Height = 20
    $tbBetreff.location = new-object system.drawing.point(20,175)
    $tbBetreff.Font = "Microsoft Sans Serif,10"
    $Form.controls.Add($tbBetreff)

    $LabelCat = New-Object system.windows.Forms.Label
    $LabelCat.Text = "Description*"
    $LabelCat.AutoSize = $true
    $LabelCat.Width = 25
    $LabelCat.Height = 10
    $LabelCat.location = new-object system.drawing.point(20,315)
    $LabelCat.Font = "Arial Narrow,12,style=Bold"
    $Form.controls.Add($LabelCat)

    $LabelCat = New-Object system.windows.Forms.Label
    $LabelCat.Text = "Please describe your Problem"
    $LabelCat.AutoSize = $true
    $LabelCat.Width = 25
    $LabelCat.Height = 10
    $LabelCat.location = new-object system.drawing.point(20,335)
    $LabelCat.Font = "Arial Narrow,11"
    $Form.controls.Add($LabelCat)

    $textbox4 = New-Object system.windows.Forms.TextBox
    $textbox4.Width = 540
    $textbox4.Height = 100
    $textbox4.location = new-object system.drawing.point(20,360)
    $textbox4.MultiLine = $True
    $textbox4.Font = "Arial Narrow,10"
    $Form.controls.Add($textbox4)

    ############################################# Right side ############################################# 

    $LabelAdm = New-Object system.windows.Forms.Label
    $LabelAdm.Text = "administrative information"
    $LabelAdm.AutoSize = $true
    $LabelAdm.Width = 25
    $LabelAdm.Height = 10
    $LabelAdm.location = new-object system.drawing.point(350,120)
    $LabelAdm.Font = "Arial Narrow,12,style=Bold"
    $Form.controls.Add($LabelAdm)


    $LabelUser = New-Object system.windows.Forms.Label
    $LabelUser.Text = "Ticket opened by"
    $LabelUser.AutoSize = $true
    $LabelUser.Width = 25
    $LabelUser.Height = 10
    $LabelUser.location = new-object system.drawing.point(350,155)
    $LabelUser.Font = "Arial Narrow,10,style=Bold"
    $Form.controls.Add($LabelUser)


    $LabelUser = New-Object system.windows.Forms.Label
    $LabelUser.Text = "$ActiveUser1"
    $LabelUser.AutoSize = $true
    $LabelUser.Width = 25
    $LabelUser.Height = 10
    $LabelUser.location = new-object system.drawing.point(350,175)
    $LabelUser.Font = "Arial Narrow,10"
    $Form.controls.Add($LabelUser)


    $LabelUser = New-Object system.windows.Forms.Label
    $LabelUser.Text = "Affected application"
    $LabelUser.AutoSize = $true
    $LabelUser.Width = 25
    $LabelUser.Height = 10
    $LabelUser.location = new-object system.drawing.point(350,205)
    $LabelUser.Font = "Arial Narrow,10,style=Bold"
    $Form.controls.Add($LabelUser)

    $LabelUser = New-Object system.windows.Forms.Label
    $LabelUser.Text = "FIS (Finance Suite)"
    $LabelUser.AutoSize = $true
    $LabelUser.Width = 25
    $LabelUser.Height = 10
    $LabelUser.location = new-object system.drawing.point(350,225)
    $LabelUser.Font = "Arial Narrow,10"
    $Form.controls.Add($LabelUser)


    $LabeApp = New-Object system.windows.Forms.Label
    $LabeApp.Text = "Coordinator-Group"
    $LabeApp.AutoSize = $true
    $LabeApp.Width = 25
    $LabeApp.Height = 10
    $LabeApp.location = new-object system.drawing.point(350,255)
    $LabeApp.Font = "Arial Narrow,10,style=Bold"
    $Form.controls.Add($LabeApp)


    $LabelUser = New-Object system.windows.Forms.Label
    $LabelUser.Text = "$CoordinatorGroup"
    $LabelUser.AutoSize = $true
    $LabelUser.Width = 25
    $LabelUser.Height = 10
    $LabelUser.location = new-object system.drawing.point(350,275)
    $LabelUser.Font = "Arial Narrow,10"
    $Form.controls.Add($LabelUser)

    ############################################# Buttons ############################################# 

    $Bcancel = New-Object system.windows.Forms.Button
    $Bcancel.Text = "Cancel"
    $Bcancel.Width = 90
    $Bcancel.Height = 30
    $Bcancel.location = new-object system.drawing.point(370,490)
    $Bcancel.Font = "Arial Narrow,12,style=Bold"
    $Form.controls.Add($Bcancel)

    $Bsend = New-Object system.windows.Forms.Button
    $Bsend.Text = "Send"
    $Bsend.Width = 90
    $Bsend.Height = 30
    $Bsend.location = new-object system.drawing.point(470,490)
    $Bsend.Font = "Arial Narrow,12,style=Bold"
    $Form.controls.Add($Bsend)


    ############################################# Button Events #############################################

#Add Button event 
$Bcancel.add_click({$form.Close})

 [void]$Form.ShowDialog()
$Form.Dispose()
```

I've seen some guys with similar problems on stack overflow, but their solutions didn't work for me.

Does somebody know what went wrong here?

Thank you!

Comment: No doesn't work either. I also updated all the names of the labels. They had equal names. But that didn't work either.

Comment: Your `$form.close` is missing the `()`.

Comment: They are already there  -> ({$form.Close})

Comment: `({$form.Close})` -> `({$form.Close()})` Close is a method, without `()` it's going to display the overloads in the terminal window.

Comment: It's working right now! Thank you!